# WSO2 AM (1.10.0) behind F5 Proxy Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

My organization has changed proxy server to F5. There is a WSO2 AM behind the server and cannot been connected from outside. the following is a list of ciphers supported by API Manager,

[image: list of Ciphers]

I was told by security architect that it seems that the ciphers and/or the key exchange on the api manager server are not accepted on the F5. the following link is a list of cipher supported by F5, https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K11444.

I was wondering if the cipher suite supported by F5 below is same to the highlighted one in above picture.

[image]

If not match, how can I add the additional cipher suite into wso2 AM server's supported list?

Thanks a lot, Sean

Comment: API Manager uses Java SSL implementation so if you need to tweak ciphers, you may refer to Oracle´s documentation. I´d also double check the information your security architect gave to you: try to enable Java´s SSL debugging options and/or use a protocol analyzer such as Wireshark in order to get more evidence on what´s going on.

Comment: Thanks Philippe I have edited the question as I founded a list of ciphers supported by API Manager, but not sure if it matches in F5 server and no idea how to add additional cipher suites into API Manager Server.